# How to select non-distinct rows with a distinct on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found many answers on selecting non-distinct rows where they group by a singular column, for example, e-mail. However, there seems to have been issue in our system where we are getting some duplicate data whereby everything is the same except the identity column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      COLUMN1,
      COLUMN2,
      COLUMN3,
      ...
      COLUMN14
  FROM TABLE1
```

How can I get the non-distinct rows from the query above? Ideally it would include the identity column as currently that is obviously missing from the distinct query.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for this?  I'm having a hard time understanding what your expected result is.

Comment: It's basically people's contact details, where there are double entries for some people and the only difference is the ID column

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 
from TABLE_NAME 
group by COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: also dont select the id column as it would be always distinct .

Answer (score 1):

```
With _cte (col1, col2, col3, id) As
    (
        Select cOl1, col2, col3, Count(*)
          From mySchema.myTable
          Group By Col1, Col2, Col3
          Having Count(*) > 1
    )
Select t.*
From _Cte As c
Join mySchema.myTable As t
On c.col1 = t.col1
And c.col2 = t.col2
And c.col3 = t.col3
```

Comment: The descriptions are not very descriptive but it helped me. Basically first it does the aggregation to find duplicates. Then it finds whole rows from the table based on a comparison of multiple columns from the aggregation (the inner join part) and gives out just the columns of the original table.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL 1, COL 2, .... COL N ORDER BY COL M
) RN
FROM TABLE_NAME 
)T
 WHERE T.RN>1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).